# How to solve the object issue in clickable state field in odoo10?

Tags: odoo-10

I have a model with clickable selection field

*****py*****

```
state = fields.Selection([('new', 'New'), ('in_progress', 'In Progress'), ('done', 'Done')], default='new')
```

*****xml*****

```
field name="state" widget="statusbar" clickable="True"
```

****function****

```
@api.onchange('state')
def onchange_state(self):
    print self
```

****notes****

it  printes like this

****** odoo.models.NewId object at 0x7f624b7b7b90******

> **questions**
>
> is it possible to get the id of the record based on this clickable
>   selection field in onchange event?

Comment: may i ask what you want to do with id?

Comment: @ ADVALAKI
I want to invoke a method and i pass id to it

Comment: Then you can simply pass  your_method(self.id) the odoo.models.NewId object at 0x7f624b7b7b90 is work as id while calling or passing argument to method

Comment: @ ADVALAKI
Thanks, I will try that

Answer (score -1):

> **If statusbar is clickable then onchange method won't call. It will
>   directly call write method.**

In onchange method, you will get id of record from "_origin" parameter, if record is already created.

Try following:

```
@api.onchange('state')
def onchange_state(self):
    record_id = self._origin.id
    #your code
```

Comment: @Emipro Technologies Pvt. Ltd.
the record_id returns False value not id

Comment: Yes its return false or if
 record already created then self has no attribute origin

Comment: @Emipro Technologies Pvt. Ltd
yes. I am creating a new record.